# JQuery Not Being Called/Working with PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call the JQuery system for use in a tab system and for some reason it is not showing the tabs in the correct way as if the JQuery is not there. I'm relatively new to JQUery and therefore I'm slightly unsure what I'm doing!
Any idea?
This is the orginal file:

```
 <head>

<style>

.ui-widget {
  font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
  font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget input,
.ui-widget select,
.ui-widget textarea,
.ui-widget button {
  font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget-content {
  border: 0px solid #aaaaaa;
  background: #ffffff url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
  color: #222222;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.ui-widget-content a {
  color: #222222;
}
.ui-widget-header {
  border: 0px solid #aaaaaa;
  background: #fff url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
  color: #222222;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.ui-widget-header a {
  color: #222222;
}

.ptable {

text-align:right;
width:40%;
margin-left:10%;

}


html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


</style>

</head>


<?php

$view = $_GET['client'];
$view = "admin";


if($view == 'public') {$selected = 2; } else {
$selected=0; }

if($view == 'admin') {
if(isset($_POST['date'])) { $selected = 6; }
if(isset($_POST['subpayment2'])) { $selected = 4; }
if(isset($_POST['subfebooking'])) {$selected = 2; }
if(isset($_POST['subberth'])) {$selected = 2; }
if(isset($_POST['nrepair'])) {$selected = 8; }
if(isset($_POST['rtype'])) {$selected = 8; }
if(isset($_POST['erepair'])) {$selected = 8; }
if(isset($_POST['srepair'])) {$selected = 8; }
if(isset($_POST['editform'])) {$selected = 2; }
if(isset($_POST['editberth'])) {$selected = 2; }
if(isset($_POST['fedit'])) {$selected = 2; }
if(isset($_POST['submitrepair'])) {$selected = 8; }
if(isset($_POST['clear'])) {$selected = 1; }
if(isset($_POST['adddates'])) {$selected = 1; }
if(isset($_POST['confirmusage'])) {$selected = 1; }
if(isset($_POST['delusage'])) {$selected = 1; }
if(isset($_POST['viewusage'])) {$selected = 1; }
if(isset($_POST['submitusage'])) {$selected = 1; }
if(isset($_POST['sailingid'])) {$selected = 9; }
if(isset($_POST['delberth'])) {$selected = 2; }
if(isset($_POST['delform'])) {$selected = 2; }
if(isset($_GET['date'])) {$selected = 1; }
if(isset($_POST['GMsignin'])) {$selected = 3; }
if(isset($_POST['Gsignin'])) {$selected = 3; }
if(isset($_POST['completeGMS'])) {$selected = 3; }
if(isset($_POST['option'])) {$selected = 1; }
if(isset($_POST['usagedate'])) {$selected = 1; }
if(isset($_POST['addusage'])) {$selected = 1; }

}


echo "<script>
$(function() {
$( '#tabs' ).tabs({
active: ".$selected."

});
});
</script>";




//echo "<div style='margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;margin-top:5%;margin-bottom:5%;max-width:100%;'><h1><IMG SRC='/images/logo.png' width='40%;'></h1>";


 echo "<div id='tabs' style='font-family:Arial;color:#4d4d4c;'>";
   echo" <ul>";
if($view == 'public') {
echo "<li><a href='#tabs-1'>Sign up!</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='#tabs-2'>Newsletter</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='#tabs-3'>Report Issue</a></li>";

} else if($view =='admin') {
echo "<li><a href='#tabs-1'>Sign up!</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='#tabs-2'>Newsletter</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='#tabs-3'>Report Issue</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='#tabs-4'>Issues</a></li>";

}

echo "</ul>";

echo "<div id='tabs-1' style='font-family:Arial;color:#4d4d4c;border:1px solid;'>";
echo "<h2 style='font-size:2em;font-weight:300;font-family:helvetica neue, helvetica;'>Sign Up!</h2>";

 require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/components/com_techybox/'.$full_path.'MS.signup.php');

 echo "</div>";


echo "<div id='tabs-2' style='font-family:Arial;color:#4d4d4c;border:1px solid;'>";
echo "<h2 style='font-size:2em;font-weight:300;font-family:helvetica neue, helvetica;'>Newsletter</h2>";

 require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/components/com_techybox/'.$full_path.'MS.newsletter.php');

 echo "</div>";

     if($view == 'admin') {

  echo "<div id='tabs-3' style='font-family:Arial;color:#4d4d4c;border:1px solid;'>";
   echo "<h2 style='font-size:2em;font-weight:300;font-family:helvetica neue, helvetica;'>issues</h2>";

require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/components/com_techybox/'.$full_path.'IMS.issues.php');

     echo "</div>";

     }

echo "</div>";
?>
```

This is the header file where the JQuery is called from. The files listed in here exist in exactly the right place so therefore this is not the issue:

```
<?php
?>
<style>
<?php include 'JOOMLA_FORFIXINGWHENREADY/modules/mod_xpertaccess/assets/css/xpertaccess.css'; ?>
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="JOOMLA_FORFIXINGWHENREADY/components/com_techybox/assets/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
});
</script>

<style>
.calbox{
width:14%;
height:100px;
border-bottom:solid thin #000;
border-right:   solid thin #000;

float:left;

}



#nav a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-left:20px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;


}
#nav a : hover{
    color: #CCC; 



}
.box{

    width:14.82%;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:1px #CCCCCC solid;
    border-right:1px #CCCCCC solid;
    text-align: center;


}   

.box2{

    width:40%;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:1px #CCCCCC solid;
    border-right:1px #CCCCCC solid;
    text-align: center;


}
    .line{
clear: left;
border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
} 

.title{

text-align:center;


}

.tttitle{

color: #b20202;

}

.personaltime{

text-align:center;


}

.hidden{

float:left;
z-index: 1000;
width: 250px;
height:auto;
position: absolute;
background-color:#fff;
visibility:collapse;
border: 1px solid black;
padding-left:10px;


-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft-radius: 10px;

border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;

}
.click:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.close:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}

</style>
```

Sorry this was so long! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please open your browser's console window and tell us what errors are shown when viewing your page, if any.

Comment: Are you certain that `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js` is the correct path?  --  Also view your console (Hit F12) and click on the NET/Network section and view if there are any 404 errors.

Comment: @Zak That's right path. I seriously have my own doubts for those who voted that comment up.\

Comment: @lleaff Seriously? This takes it whatever the current protocol is. Know it guys!

Comment: @PraveenKumar I know now you quick beast :D

Comment: This is the console error? Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @lleaff Then why did you ask? :P

Comment: @BConstable There you are. Try to solve that issue.

Comment: @PraveenKumar you are too quick, I deleted my comment 10 secs after making it -_-

Comment: All code that uses jQuery has to be after the inclusion of the jQuery script,

Comment: @PraveenKumar all those resources appear to be there. I can show you the file

Comment: 500 means a failed server side code somewhere ..  Possibly your include ..

Comment: @BConstable The issue is not because of a resource not found, but because of some internal server error. Check your PHP code.

Comment: Check apache and php error logs.  that should point you in the right direction

Comment: [01-Jan-2016 22:14:34 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: full_path in /home/thetech1/public_html/JOOMLA_FORFIXINGWHENREADY/components/com_techybox/MS.manageadmin.php on line 141